# What are the possible logging plugins for Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am using Cakephp, but I am unable to log the info and errors in log files because it doesn't work with Configure::write('debug',0) and I can't set it to 1 or 2 or 3 on my production system.

I tried log4php, but it also not helps me as I want to log different error types in different files. Can anyone suggest me some other plugin for logging which Cakephp supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to the logs without debug being set to 0, just write to the log using:

```
$this->log("I am testing the logging without debug being turned on!", 'debug');
```

You can get more information here.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1194/Logging#!/view/1195/Writing-to-logs